# Downloading csv file from FTP server

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to download a csv file from our FTP every evening.  I'm getting an error when I attempt to run the script saying "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed".  Here's the code I'm using:

```
import ftplib


ftp = ftplib.FTP('http://192.168.0.00', 'username', 'password')
files = ftp.dir('/')
ftp.cwd("/")
filematch = '*.csv'
target_dir = '/path/to/csv/file'
import os

for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    target_file_name = os.path.join(target_dir,os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(target_file_name,'wb') as fhandle:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %filename, fhandle.write)
```

Not sure what exactly is wrong with my code.  Could it be something with the directory formatting, or the FTP format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature `ftplib.FTP()` is

```
  ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])
```

So you need to provide a *hostname* as a first argument not an *URL*.

Make it

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.00', 'username', 'password')
```

P.S. Is it really `192.168.0.00` with a `00` as the last octet?

Comment: Thank you!  I'm no longer getting the error, but for some reason I can't see the files under my downloads.  When I run the script through the command prompt it returns several rows of "drwxr-xr-x" followed by the different folder names in the FTP.

Comment: And no that was just a sample IP I provided.